# In SwiftUI, how to change button color when clicked in right order?

Tags: swiftui

I am learning SwiftUI, and I am working on an App, which is a 5*5 grids, with 1 to 25 number displayed randomly in the grids. Users must click the number in the right order, from 1 to 25. When the expected number tapped, the button changes color, else show err message.
I tried many different methods, but still doesn't work.
[image]

I'd like to learn how to check the number, and change its background color.

Comment: Could you show us the code you have written?

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.